# Cant get the logic of this code

Tags: c, arrays

How does this code work for the input : 20051996

Program: to delete the duplication elements in array

```
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
       { 
          if (a[i]==a[j])
          { 
            for(k=j;k<n;k++)
             {
               a[k]=a[k+1];
             }
            n--;
            j--;
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: is n equal to the size of the array?

Comment: yes, n= array.length

Comment: yes n is equal to the size of the array.

Comment: Shouldn't `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` be `for(i=0; i<(n-1); i++)` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is pretty simple here the element is not deleted but it is being exchanged.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
   { 
      if (a[i]==a[j])
```

this is for finding the element which is equal to the `a [i]`. As we get the number there is another loop which is targeting the repeated number and then that cell is fed/replaced with next cell value. As one value has been changed so all the remaining cell value is swapped with the next one.

```
for(k=j;k<n;k++)
         {
           a[k]=a[k+1];
         }
        n--;
        j--;
```

And now the last cell remains and the number n and j is decreased so that it does not refer to that cell again. It removes the extra element but also makes a new element you have to put a counter to get the number of repetition and then you have to slice the array or break it to make that work.

Comment: What about the out-of-bounds access?

Comment: i understood the logic @ahshis sah, but for input [1,0,0,7,1,9,9,5] still have a doubt in iteration during 1st iteration of the loop (i=0;j=1) the array will be [1,0,0,7,1,9,9,5] . In the second iteration (i=1;j=2) the array will be [1,0,7,1,9,9,5]. like this if the iteration follows how will that 1 which repeats gets swapped? the output must be [1,0,7,9,5]

Comment: it's not being swapped, It is being replaced ```a[k]=a[k+1];``` as it got the element which is repeated then that repeated cell is replaced with the next value. After that loop also exchanges all element with their next one

Comment: so finally you have vanished that repeated element...to make this work you need to use a variable as counter...and then manipulate it

Answer (score 1):

The code iterates through the array and for every cell iterates through the remaining cells checking if that cell is equal to the previous.  When it finds an equal one it then proceeds through the remaining cell setting each cell equal to the next one, basically shifting the array over one.  Upon doing that it decrements n to represent the new size of the row and decrements j to have it perform a new check on the array.  One issue i could see arising is on

```
        for(k=j;k<n;k++)
         {
           a[k]=a[k+1];
         }
```

When the code goes to check the last cell it will try to copy data from the cell after it, and since there is none there will be an error.
You should add a check for that or just not have it check the last cell.   If your shifting the array you should not longer need to care about the last cell.

In addition it should be good to note that while your shifting the array values over your not exactly changing the size of the array or deleting the older cells.

For that input [2,0,0,5,1,9,9,6]

The program would change the array to [2,0,5,1,9,9,6,6] and should crash on the last one.